# Setting Focus on a TextBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010, vwdexpress

I have a small ASP.net web app for sales, when the "Make New Sale" page loads, I want the TextBox for the Barcode to be in focus, so that the user doesn't have to navigate to it and click it then enter the Barcode, how can I do that?

PS: I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 and VB.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this either in your code behind, or directly in JavaScript on your page. To do it in your code behind, just call the `Focus()` method on the control:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

To do it in JavaScript, create a function that selects the textbox and calls its `.focus()` method, and call the function in the page's `onLoad` event:

```
function SetFocus() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");
    if(textbox != null) {
        textbox.focus();
    }
}
```